# grouped collection select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in the early stages of developing a dynamic drop-down menu for a signup form.

I have four  models.

```
City
has_many :burroughs
has_many :hoods

Burrough
belongs_to :city
has_many :hoods

Hood
belongs_to :city
belongs_to :burrough

User
Belongs_to :city
Belongs_to :burrough (this can be nil, or needs to be able to be nil)
Belongs_to :hood
```

My goal is to create a dropdown-select.  NYC (city) is divided into burroughs (ie Brooklyn) which is then divided into hoods (ie. Park Slope, Williamsburg).

For another city, I would like to skip the burrough and just go straight from city (boston) to hood (Cambridge) Although I'm not even quite that far yet.

Here are my tables

```
create_table "hoods", force: true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.integer  "burrough_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "city_id"
end

create_table "burroughs", force: true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.integer  "city_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "cities", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "name"
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "email"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "password_digest"
t.string   "remember_token"
t.boolean  "admin",              default: false
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
t.string   "city_id"
t.string   "hood_id"
t.string   "burrough_id"
end
```

I've been looking at [RailCast 88](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jO5SpYctA-s) and I've gotten this far:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :city_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :city_id, City.order(:id), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
</div>
<div id="neighbselect">
    <%= f.label :burrough_id %><br>
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :burrough_id, City.order(:name), :burroughs*, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
</div>
<div id="neighbselect">
    <%= f.label :hood_id %><br>
    <%= f_collection_select :hood_id, Hood.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
</div>
```

My question is 1) * the asterisk there.  I need to define burroughs as a method, but where do I do it, and what do I define it as?  I'm not sure because

2) I'm having difficulty walking through the grouped_collection_select statement.  What is happening here?  after grouped_collection_select the :burrough_id is what?  The different burroughss based on the cities which is ordered by name? Then I have the undefined method, and then :name, :id.

I'd appreciate a little walkthrough on this one.  I'm stumped!  Thanks guys

**EDIT**
I've gotten a little farther.  I added this to my user controller...

```
def burroughs
@burroughs = Burrough.all  
end
```

I still don't seem to be getting all the burroughs underneath NYC.  Check the image...

[Drop-Down http://shiftedrecording.com/shiftedaudio/TippedTest/images/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-24%20at%202.55.26%20PM.png](http://shiftedrecording.com/shiftedaudio/TippedTest/images/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-24%20at%202.55.26%20PM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you come across a similar problem, make sure you have rake:db migrated *sigh*